# build poco c++ library on windows

Tags: c++, openssl, poco

I'm trying to build poco library (c++) with openssl on windows 10 (VS 2012). With the following cmd file:

```
@echo off
set INCLUDE=c:\openssl\include
set LIB=c:\openssl\lib
set _IsNativeEnvironment=true
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
buildwin 110 build all release x64 nosamples notests devenv
```

I get link errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Crypto, Configuration: release_shared x64 ------
1>  Datei *.dll nicht gefunden
1>  Datei *.lib nicht gefunden
1>     Creating library ..\lib64\PocoCrypto.lib and object ..\lib64\PocoCrypto.exp
1>ECKey.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_type
1>ECKeyImpl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_type
1>RSAKeyImpl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_type
1>PKCS12Container.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_type
1>EVPPKey.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_type referenced in function "private: void __cdecl Poco::Crypto::EVPPKey::newECKey(char const *)" (?newECKey@EVPPKey@Crypto@Poco@@AEAAXPEBD@Z)
...
```

(Datei *.dll nicht gefunden == file *.dll not found).

If I remove the Crypto in file "components" (Is it OK if I want to use https?), I get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NetSSL_OpenSSL, Configuration: release_shared x64 ------
1>     Creating library ..\lib64\PocoNetSSL.lib and object ..\lib64\PocoNetSSL.exp
1>Context.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol BIO_new_file referenced in function "private: void __cdecl Poco::Net::Context::initDH(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?initDH@Context@Net@Poco@@AEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
...
```

I installed openssl from "Shining Light" (win64). I also tried to use openssl which is built from source (https://github.com/pocoproject/openssl). But I get the same errors.
Can someone help me ?!

Thank you!
Xinyu

Comment: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, If I delete all object files: folder obj64, including obj64 in testsuite, then every thing is ok.